# UITableView Cells disappear after scrolling down then back up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView that has custom cells inside it. The tableview creates cells correctly initially. When I scroll Down then go back up all cells disappear. my view controller is the UITableviewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Delegate. I am implementing all required methods, namely: cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection,willDisplayCell. I am using the standard code used to display a custom tableview. Here is the tutorial I followed strictly: https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722

**My question is more abstract than technical: What causes cells to disappear upon scrolling back up?**
 I know it has to do with cell reuse but I am using willDisplayCell to properly set content, and does the indexpath change indexes upon scrolling.\

Thanks for any clarification, hint etc.

Comment: it's really use full https://github.com/timd/Pro-iOS-TableViews

Answer (score 1):

When the properties of cell are created and added in the method **cellForRowAtIndexPath** such problems occur. Create the properties in the custom class and access them after declaring custom class. For example you have a custom class named TableCell,in **viewDidLoad**

```
[yourTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
```

in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.property1 = attribute1;  //property1 already created in class TableCell
```